# Trouble with SQL Function & Case returns

Tags: oracle, plsql

Keeping it simple, I've got a table with a column called IDSTAGE holding a number (1 through 5) and am trying to create a function to take that number and return a description. Heres what I've got:

```
FUNCTION STATUS_DESC_SF (p_idstage IN BB_BASKETSTATUS.IDSTAGE%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN p_idstage = 1 THEN RETURN '1 - Order Submitted'
        WHEN p_idstage = 2 THEN RETURN '2 - Accepted, sent to shipping'
        WHEN p_idstage = 3 THEN RETURN '3 - Back-ordered'
        WHEN p_idstage = 4 THEN RETURN '4 - Cancelled'
        WHEN p_idstage = 5 THEN RETURN '5 - Shipped'
        ELSE RETURN 'Null'
    END CASE;
END STATUS_DESC_SF;
```

When I run this, and show err i get the following for every line beginning with when.

```
6/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
         The symbol ";" was substituted for "WHEN" to continue.
```

I've done my due diligence and double checked my syntax and as far as I can tell, I've not done anything wrong. I suspect it doesn't like the THEN RETURN part, but thats not where the error is appearing.

Comment: _SQL*Plus is a command-line interface for the Oracle RDBMS product. SQL*Plus questions should probably be also tagged with oracle._

Comment: Here you go, documentation specifically for Oracle PL/SQL: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php The issue is syntax is slightly different between RDBMS, that's why you might run into issues if you try to apply "standard" SQL to your specific RDBMS which may do some things that are not standard.

Comment: AHhh, so the semicolons are needed at the end the THEN [result]. That was very helpful thank you

Comment: case _expressions_ return a value. They can be used everywhere an expression can be used, typically in SELECT etc. In stored procedures/functions (plsql) there are also case _statements_, used for conditional execution of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RETURN CASE
    WHEN p_idstage = 1 THEN '1 - Order Submitted'
    WHEN p_idstage = 2 THEN '2 - Accepted, sent to shipping'
    WHEN p_idstage = 3 THEN '3 - Back-ordered'
    WHEN p_idstage = 4 THEN '4 - Cancelled'
    WHEN p_idstage = 5 THEN '5 - Shipped'
    ELSE 'Null'
END;
```

Case is an expression

Comment: You just need to remove the final `CASE` from the `END CASE`, as this is returning a case expression, not a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the lack of semicolons at the end of the then result lines. In SQL they aren't needed, but within a PLSQL Function they are.

Corrected code:

```
FUNCTION STATUS_DESC_SF
    (p_idstage IN BB_BASKETSTATUS.IDSTAGE%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN p_idstage = 1 THEN RETURN '1 - Order Submitted';
        WHEN p_idstage = 2 THEN RETURN '2 - Accepted, sent to shipping';
        WHEN p_idstage = 3 THEN RETURN '3 - Back-ordered';
        WHEN p_idstage = 4 THEN RETURN '4 - Cancelled';
        WHEN p_idstage = 5 THEN RETURN '5 - Shipped';
        ELSE RETURN 'Null';
    END CASE;
END;
```

Thanks to kutschkem for providing a good resource for learning proper syntax.

Comment: IMO, it would be far better to have the CASE statement as an expression, as per kutschkem's answer. In general, a function should have few exit points - your case expression has 7 (the 6 returns plus exceptions). It's also easier to debug a case expression in SQL. By defining the value you wish to return before returning it, you reduce the exit points in your function and IMO make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Good Idea. Though I don't fully understand how using a case to change a lv and return it is any different than using a case to select a return beyond the readability. Perhaps I'll come to understand it as I learn more.

Comment: It's the difference between "if this value, return this, if that value, return that, etc" and "find the value and return that"; it's clearer what your intent is if you do the latter; it's easier to debug (IMO), to see the program flow.